# The Beta function but with arbitrary integral bounds

Tags: integration, reference-request, beta-function

In my research, I need to calculate $\int_a^bx^m(1-x)^ndx$ where $a<b$ are real numbers and $m,n$ are nonnegative integers. Before I derive it myself, is it written somewhere? I am looking for references.

Comment: This is called the incomplete Beta function (or the difference between two of them).  In your particular case with integers you can do it by integration by parts, but should expect it to be the sum of $m$ or $n$ terms.  See for example 8.17.5 of https://dlmf.nist.gov/8.17 which deals with the case where your $a=0$ (plus other notation changes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [incomplete beta function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteBetaFunction.html) defines:
$$B(y;m+1,n+1)=\int_0^yx^m(1-x)^ndx$$
and so your result will just be:
$$B(b;m+1,n+1)-B(a;m+1,n+1)$$